# GPIO edge detection -> notifying a web client

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket.io, raspberry-pi, gpio

So I believe the crux of my issue is that the python GPIO event detection is threaded, and so is the Socket.IO Emit stuff. I'm trying to call an Emit when a GPIO event detection fires. And I'm getting errors with not awaiting the socket.io.emit, when I attempt to throw an await in front of it I get bad syntax.

Anyway I'm simply trying to send messages up to a web client when an interrupt happens on the IO. For example an LED blink happens I want to send that up to the client. Using socket.io does the message to the client part, and GPIO interrupts via event detection does the other part (without tying up the app) I just need to send those event detections from GPIO to the socket.io emits somehow.

Also I'm using a Sanic web server.

Anyway here's the code:

```py
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='sanic')

app = Sanic()
sio.attach(app)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)


#this gets called when the gpio.add_event_detect event is hit upon the gpio pin #going high (led lighting up). This works fine except sio.emit needs to be #awaited, but if I throw an await in front of it I get bad syntax, I put async #in front of the function def and then I get errors saying I never awaited the #function my_callback_one when it gets called from the GPIO.add_event_detect #event firing. I'm not sure what to do or if this is possible.

def my_callback_one(channel):
    sio.emit('my_response', {'data': 'test'})
    print('========button press LED lighting detected========')

GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback_one)


#Starts the web application
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port= 8090, workers=4)
```

Under normal circumstances I could do emits from the web server in a threaded fashion like so:

```py
async def background_task():

     count = 0
     while count < 10:
         await sio.sleep(.05)
         print("message sent to client")
         count += 1
         await sio.emit('my_response', {'data': count})
    pass

@app.listener('before_server_start')
def before_server_start(sanic, loop):
    sio.start_background_task(background_task)
```

Which works fine, but as soon as I try to do that sio.emit from the gpio callback (another thread) I get issues with not awaiting the sio.emit. I've tried making my def my_callback_one(channel) asyc defined and that didn't help. (async def my_callback_one(channel))

I know this is a threading issue but I'm just not sure where to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a "@sio.event" before the function, telling sanic that is a socket event (with async and await also well). Here's an example:

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/blob/master/examples/server/sanic/app.py